# How to achieve data polymorphism for multiple external formats in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, serialization, type-conversion

I need to process multiple formats and versions for semantically equivalent data.

I can generate Haskell data types for each schema (XSD for example), they will be technically different, but semantically and structurally identical in many cases.

The data is complex, includes references, and service components must process whole graph and produce also similar response (a component might just update a field, but might need to analyze whole graph to collect all required information, might call other services as well).

- How can I represent `ns1:address` and `ns2:adress` as one polymorphic type that has `country` and `street` elements and application needs process them as identical, but keeps serialization context for writing response in correct format (one representation might encode them in single string while other might carry also superfluous complex data)?
- How close can I get to writing mostly code that defines semantic equivalence of data, business logic and generate all else? What features in Haskell language or libraries should I evaluate as building blocks for potential solution?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to create a data type for each schema and create a function to map them to a common data type. Process it as you wish. You don't need to create polymorphic types.

This approach is similar to Pandoc's: you get a bunch of readers to parse documents to a common document structure, then use writers to convert that common structure to a particular format.

You just need the libraries to read your complex input data (and write it back, if necessary). The rest is functions and data types.

If you are really handling graphs, you can look at [the `Data.Graph` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Graph.html).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a problems that is well served by the Type Class infrastructure, and the `Lens` library.

- Use a Type Class to define a standard and consistent high-level interface to the various implementations. Make sure that you focus on the operations you wish to perform, not on the underlying implementation or process.
- Use `Lens`es and `Prism`s to reach into the underlying datatypes and return answers to queries, and modify values "in-place", without resorting to full serialisation/de-serialisation.